# Какое окончание использовать?

Tags: орфография

> Он не *исправим_* неряха

Какое окончание использовать?

Comment: @Diman, В чем именно у вас сомнения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю смысл Вашего прежложения, то "-ый" - "неисправимый".
Только исправьте ошибку. "Неисправимый" в данном случае пишется слитно: "не" с прилагательными, когда частица образует слово, противоположное по значению исходному, пишется слитно. Кроме того, слово "неисправимый" можно заменить синонимом, например, "безнадежный".

Answer (score 1):

Это существительное общего рода, поскольку в данном случае даётся мужской род /он/, то неисправимый, если она, то неисправимая.

Answer (score 0):

кто сможет написать слова с окончанием "ЁЙ"???